# Validating EMail field with Authlogic

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model, authlogic, email-validation

I have just started new application for practice purpose and want email-field validation on registration page. I have googled for that and got the solution as

```
class user < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :username
  validates_format_of :email, :with => /SomeRegexpYouGotFromGoogle/
end
```

But i have heard that Authlogic can do that much better. I have also got the method of Authlogic i.e.

```
Authlogic::ActsAsAuthentic::Email
```

But i dont know how to use it in my project. Please suggest me a direction to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The following link might help you. 
[Authologic usage for email validation](http://saravani.wordpress.com/2012/01/03/rails-3-authlogic-implementation-a-basic-tutorial/)

Or
The follow link also for how to use authologic just try it 
[Rails 3 example using Authlogic](https://github.com/trevmex/authlogic_rails3_example.git)